# Sublime vintage mode paste in insert mode

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm following one tutorial and it says I have to use `Ctrl + R` to paste in insert mode, but when I try hitting that combination I get the `Goto symbol...` as that's predefined in Sublime. Now, I'm wondering is there some other shortcut to paste in insert mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @roma pointed out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> is [not supported](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html).

My use case was: I used the comand `c%` which selects the text between the matching brackets and automatically goes to the insert mode. As pointed out in the comment to roma's answer: using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> doesn't work after the `c%` command.

The workaround is to press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key after `c%` command, which brings us to the command mode, and then press the <kbd>p</kbd> key to paste the text previously selected by `c%` command.

Answer (score 0):

Insert mode is regular Sublime Text 2 editing, with the usual Sublime Text 2 key bindings: vi insert mode key bindings are not emulated.  [from there](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html)

Why you don't want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>?

Comment: for example if I select the text with command c% which selects everything between matching brackets, then I automatically go to the insert mode and there I can't use Ctrl + v to paste that text (it pastes something else that was(still is) in the clipboard)